# Dask Dataframe - Many tasks/partitions for small dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have been using Dask to process large dataframes and do things like joins/filters. The end result is a dataframe that I know has 8 rows. However, if my dask dataframe is `f`, where I check `f` I get `npartitions=81` and `Dask Name: assign, 10633 tasks`. Why is that? It took almost 5 hours to write to an .h5 file just for me to find out that there are only 8 rows in the result. Is there a way I can speed this up?

The number of partitions was 81, which seemed too high. I lowered it to 5 and it still took 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't matter.  In the end you'll have lots of empty partitions, but that's ok.  If you are about this then you can always call `df.repartition(1)`.

The number of partitions of your output is a function of the number of input partitions, and the operations that you do.  However it doesn't take into account the values of your data (all of this is determined before Dask ever looks at your data).

If Dask is slow, then I recommend taking a look at the "Understanding Performance" page on the Dask documentation in order to learn why.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html